# Filling points to a simplex in models for EG

Tags: gr.group-theory, gt.geometric-topology, mg.metric-geometry, geometric-group-theory, classifying-spaces

I have a question which is related to higher Dehn functions of groups.

I also have a group $G$ with a finite $K(G,1)$. Let us denote by $EG$ the universal cover of this complex. We choose a path-metric on $K(G,1)$, e.g., the canonical one coming from glueing the simplices, and lift it to a path-metric on $EG$. Now, I’m given $n+1$ vertices of $EG$ (not necessarily close together) and I want to know how much space it takes me to fill these $n+1$ points to a topological $n$-simplex in $EG$. I can do this inductively: first I connect the vertices since $EG$ is path-connected. Then I fill every loop I see with a disc since $EG$ is simply-connected, etc. Every time I fill in an $(n+1)$-disc into an $n$-sphere, the space this filling needs is governed by the $n$-th Dehn function of this complex which is equivalent to the $n$-th Dehn function of the group $G$.

Now I need the following statement: for every $S>0$ there exists an $R>0$ such that whatever $n$ is, the space I need to fill $n$ points that are a mutual distance $\leq S$ apart is at most $R$. In general it is not possible to prove such a statement, because the higher $n$ is, the more induction steps I have to do in the construction above and hence the space I need to fill the $n$ points will grow with $n$, even if the $n$ points we start with are close together. But in my situation I have a finite $K(G,1)$ and so the question is if it is possible to prove the statement I need under this assumption? The rough idea would be that I do the induction up to the dimension of the complex $K(G,1)$ increasing at every step the space I need for the fillings, but once I reach the dimension of the complex I can go on with my construction into higher dimensions, but now the space I need at these steps above the dimension does not increase any more (because now I only use the space that I have already used). Can this be the case?

The question is a bit motivated by the fact that [Alonso-Wang-Pride](https://www.degruyter.com/downloadpdf/j/jgth.1999.2.issue-1/jgth.1999.008/jgth.1999.008.pdf) proved that the higher Dehn functions of a group $G$ in degrees higher than the dimension of a $K(G,1)$ are equivalent to linear functions.

Comment: I am a bit confused here. Can't you just connect your points with a tree in the 1-skeleton?

Comment: But how do you control then the space you need for your filling? Using a fixed tree will not work - you will have to choose a different one for each set of points. How to choose the tree then?